# Momentjs - Get most recent Friday

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the start of (12:00am, or, 00:00am) of the most recent Friday. This has been working:

`moment().isoWeekday(5).startOf('day').toDate()`

But it only works Friday->Sunday, on Monday morning it will then refer to the upcoming Friday, in which case this would work:

`moment().add('-1', 'week').day(5).startOf('day').toDate()`

but I need it be dynamic and done in one line if possible, to where I don't to perform any checks on the current day.

Is there a way to always get the **most recent Friday?** Regardless of what the current day is.

**Edit** I'm also trying to get this to return the current day (friday) if executed on a Friday.

Comment: Always subtract 5 days? `moment().add('-5', 'days').day(5).startOf('day').toDate()`

Comment: Thanks @DanielDiekmeier. Will that get the current day if executed on a Friday? Essential i'm trying to treat Friday as the start of the week.

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier through my own testing it looks like it will. Since -5 from a Friday will get Sunday, and works within the same week. Perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library, it's pretty straight forward

```js
var date = new Date();
while ( date.getDay() !== 5 ) date.setDate(date.getDate() -1);

console.log(date)
```

With moment

```
var date = moment();

var friday = date.day(date.day() >= 5 ? 5 :-2);
```

and if millisecond accuracy doesn't matter, you could call `moment()` twice to make it one line *(but I would much raher use a variable)*

```
var friday = moment().day(moment().day() >= 5 ? 5 :-2);
```

Comment: I've been using `.isoWeekday` where I can over `.day`. What is the `-2` doing in this instance?

Comment: That's saying if the current day is >= 5 (friday), then get that date, other wise get the day minus 2? so that works for Sunday, what about Saturday? (if Im understanding correctly)

Comment: `5` is the number for friday, if it's already more than `5`, i.e. after friday that week, return `5`, otherwise return `-2`. With `day()`, doing `day(0)` would always be monday, so `day(-2)` would always be friday.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. Take a look at a the solution @daniel posted in a comment to my original post. Is that better/same? I guess his just does what yours does in a different way, leveraging the `.add` method.

Comment: @elzi - it goes back five days, and then sets the day to friday. I suppose that works as well, I haven't really tested it, and don't know moment.js that well either, I've never really needed it.

Comment: Okay awesome. To confirm - Will this return the current day if ran on a Friday?

Comment: Thanks @adeneo I will accept your solution. For future readers - @ DanielDiekmeier solution in comments works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
var date = moment().utc().isoWeekday(5);
if(moment().day() < 5) {
  date = date.add(-1, 'week');
}

console.log('Recent friday starts:', date.startOf('day').toDate());

console.log('Recent friday ends:', date.endOf('day').toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will that 'recent friday' get the current friday, if executed on a friday though?

Comment: because of -1 week, so it will give past friday even if You call it on friday

Comment: Yeah sorry if I wasnt clear, I need it to return the current day if ran on a friday, not the previous of the last week. That's why I tried to use the language "most recent" friday.

Comment: @elzi check latest changes, I've moved data in my computer and checked, it works as You want. please keep in mind that to work with dates it's more safe to use UTC timezone, fill free to remove `.utc()` if You want to get data by local (client's) timezone

Comment: Thanks @num8er for your efforts but this still isnt quite it. Good points on UTC though. Look at the other answers for an example of what I was trying to achieve. Your solution is still getting me a friday in the future. I need to always get the most recent Friday that is in the past, or if the day is currently friday, to get the current day.

Comment: @elzi (: I've not read Your question carefully, so adeneo is right, You've to check the current day. good luck man